# DB2 numeric values shown with no decimal places, linked server in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, decimal, linked-server

I have an issue running queries against DB2 database.
Numeric values for some columns are returned whitout decimal places e.g. I have a field `VPACKSP.VPTARA` which contains tara weight.

Running a query like this

```
SELECT VPACKSP.VPTARA FROM VPACKSP WHERE VPACKSP.VPTEIL = 123456
```

returns value `0,000` the correct value shoud be `0,880`

Running a query where numeric value is multiplied returns correct value but multiple time higher

```
SELECT VPACKSP.VPTARA * 100 FROM VPACKSP WHERE VPACKSP.VPTEIL = 123456
```

returns value

```
88,000
```

The queries are run using ODBC 64bit ISeries Access Driver version 13.00.01.0 installed on Windows Server. The client I use is Microsoft SQL Server where a Linked server was created using OLE DB Provider for ODBC.

The actual query looks as follows:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM OPENQUERY(
  [LINKEDSERVERNAME]
,'SELECT VPACKSP.VPTARA FROM VPACKSP WHERE VPACKSP.VPTEIL = 123456'
)
;
```

This is not happening for all numeric columns.
I was trying to cast to `NUMERIC(32,16)` as well as to `DECIMAL(10,5)`, also other combinations of decimal places, but all resuts are zeros, only multiplication works. What could be possibly wrong?

Comment: SQLBindCol etc?

Comment: @jarlh Not sure hot this might help. I am not using ODBC API directly. Just running queries as described (see. update)

Comment: I found this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3051993/fix-the-value-of-number-type-is-truncated-when-you-select-data-from-an-oracle-linked-server-by-using-ole-db-provider, but after installing SQL 2014 SP2 nothing was changed

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind, Sebastian:

a) the DECIMAL data type in DB2, which stores the value as one half-byte per digit, plus Hex C for positive and Hex D for negative in the rightmost half-byte (0.880, if it's a DECIMAL(4,3), is stored in three bytes as Hex 00 88 0C), and the position of the decimal point is kept in the DBMS's metadata. So it could be translated badly by the ODBC driver.

b) Also at ODBC layer level: the driver could choke on the fact that, in Germany, you use the comma and not the dot as the decimal separator, and the driver stops as soon as it finds a character that does not expect as part of a numeric literal - your comma.

I would test your query (just the one you have between single quotes in your example), using a normal ODBC SQL client, like the Microsoft ODBC test tool, for example. I would expect that one to return the same error, and so you would have at least a bug to report.

Workaround would be to configure your language settings in Windows (maybe temporarily) to use the dot instead of the comma as the decimal separator (and the comma instead of the German dot maybe, as the thousands separator, so that you don't create a confusion).

Two hours later - another idea for a workaround: Could you try to:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(VPACKSP.VPTARA AS VARCHAR(16)) AS vptara
FROM VPACKSP 
WHERE VPACKSP.VPTEIL = 123456
```

? This way, you let DB2 perform the conversion to a string and don't leave it to the front end - just an idea ...

Good luck -

Marco the Sane

Comment: I have checked my query directly against DB2 database (without a linked server, and not in MS SQL management studio) . It returns correct result. So my guess this is issue is related to Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC and LInked server in SQL server 2014.

Comment: Did you use a DB2 client to check it directly, like the DB2 command line? That one would do the right thing. Or did you try an ODBC client through the same ODBC driver? That could narrow down the origin of the problem.

Comment: I have tried different client via the same odbc driver. So it is something related to Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: I have found these kb article but it relates to oracle, but the symptoms are similar. Installed SP2 but this is not working in my case (perhaps DB2 needs other solution) (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3051993/fix-the-value-of-number-type-is-truncated-when-you-select-data-from-an-oracle-linked-server-by-using-ole-db-provider)